# Remove the duplicate row having specific value in column from the Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I receive a excel file every day and have to process this excel file into the application before deleting some records from excel file. 
I have attached screenshot of the dataframe.I want to keep the highlighted row on index number 12 and delete rest of the  duplicate rows on index 18 and 7.

[image]

Comment: If not working let me know.

Comment: I tried but I did not get the desired output.I want to use data on index 12 and delete the rows on index number 18 and 7.

Comment: what is your code? Output is only row `12` ?

Comment: @jezrael i want all the rows except rows on index 18 and 7.I want to remove them from the dataframe.

Comment: `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['VendorPNo'])` not working?